# One DbContext Instance spans multiple Repositories

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

These are my AutoFac-DI definitions in my Web Api setup:

```
 builder.RegisterType<MyContext>().As<MyContext>().InstancePerRequest();
 builder.RegisterType<TestRepository>().InstancePerRequest();
 builder.RegisterType<SchoolclassCodeRepository>().InstancePerRequest();
 builder.RegisterType<TestService>().InstancePerRequest();
```

The TestService constructor accepts the TestRepository and SchoolclassCodeRepository. Both Repositories accepts the same Instance of the MyContext.

**I agree with this**: [Is it wise to use same DbContext with multiple repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616211/is-it-wise-to-use-same-dbcontext-with-multiple-repositories)

*There are other good reasons to share a context though, one of which (IMHO) is that the context has to track the state of an entity, if you're get an entity, dispose the context, make some modifications to the entity, and then attach to a new context this new context has to go hit the database so it can figure out the state of the entity. Likewise if you're working with graphs of entities (Invoices, and all their InvoiceItems), then the new context would have to fetch all the entities in the graph to determine their state.*

But now I hit a one-way street with this architecture!

What if I have to do a transaction spanning multiple repositories?

With EF6 you do it like that without Repositories:

```
using(NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities())
{
    DbContextTransaction transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {
        //insert record 1
        Customer obj1 = new Customer();
        obj1.CustomerID = "ABCDE";
        db.Customers.Add(obj1);
        db.SaveChanges();

        //insert record 2
        Customer obj2 = new Customer();
        obj2.CustomerID = "PQRST";
        db.Customers.Add(obj2);   
        db.SaveChanges();

        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

When I take now the above sample and try to do the same with my 2 repositories within the service, then I face a serious problem.

- I have no DbContext available in my Service.
- The DbContext is a DataProvider/Layer concern and should stay inside the repository.

How can I create then a transaction over multiple repositories without changing my repositories?

Sample what I want:

Inside my TestService I want to do roughly:

```
public void Save()
{
  // Open Transaction
  // testRepo.Insert();
  // schoolclassCodeRepo.Delete();
  // Commit Transaction
}
```

**UPDATE**

In my TestService I map all entities  from the repos to DTO objects which are then enriched by data + links (Rest) in my web api controllers.

**UPDATE 2**

- The Repository pattern makes data access methods reusable thats good.
- But it makes a transaction over multiple repositories sharing same DbContext not possible.

WOULD it not be better to implement all Repository methods as extension methods of the DbContext, this way I could call the "Repo extension methods" in my Service directly on the ONE DbContext injected into my TestService?

**UPDATE 3 Solution code**

```
public async Task<bool> DeleteSchoolyearAsync(int id)
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        try
        {
            await testRepository.DeleteTestTypes(id);
            await schoolyearRepository.DeleteAsync(id);
            scope.Complete(); // Rollback is done due to using statement...
            return true;

        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This code worked fine!

Comment: "There are other good reasons to share a context though, one of which (IMHO)" Wrong. You should never do this. In this particular case, you've just created an in memory database. Since items your static DbContext is never collected, none of the cache gets collected. Thus as t increases, more of your database gets "cached", until you run out of memory and crash or your entire database is in your cache. You've also lost Thread Safety, so you need to run in a single thread, as the cache is not thread-safe. Plus `.SaveChanges()` is going to cause side effects in other threads.

Comment: Then add to the fact that `SaveChanges()` now has to run the `ChangeTracker` across your ENTIRE cache, which is now your ENTIRE DATABASE, each call to `.SaveChanges()` will last ....oh I don't know...about 5 minutes... Except its not going to do that, because it's going to crash when another thread access the DbContext.

Comment: Doesn't ChangeTracker only track modified objects? Surely with changing two of the entities wouldn't make whole database go into memory. This is exactly what SaveChanges does. It commits all changed/added/deleted objects into db. Not the entire database. I think for this kind of problem there is Unit of work to be implemented.

Comment: How about writing the code in data access where you have access of the `DbContext`

Comment: @Eldho Then I would have to put together the TestRepository with the SchoolclassCodeRepository. This will blur the responsibility of each Repo what I do not like. Furthermore I want to have testRepo.Insert as reusable method which I can not when I put the schoolclassCode.Delete inside it...

Comment: You could try to implement UnitOfWork with your existing repos as explained in this article. At the end there is implementation of UOW with generic repositories: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/770156/Understanding-Repository-and-Unit-of-Work-Pattern

Comment: @Jure No ChangeTracker tracks NOTHING. It can't track anything since the objects are likely all POCO. Instead it stores a snapshot of all the "cells" that the object is mapped to, and then each time you call things like `.SaveChanges()` it scans all the Entities and compares the entity with the "cells". It is incredibly in-efficient. My point is that ChangeTracker keeps everything its loaded in memory, so over time the service will load the entire database into "cache", since the mechanism for "freeing" memory is to dispose the DbContext.

Comment: @Aron: I wasn't aware that there are two mechanisms in EF to perform change tracking: snapshot based and proxy based. I guest proxy based change tracking is used when properties are marked virtual.

Comment: @Jure Try it...as you increase the number of items in your `DbContext` the time to run `ChangeTracker` increases.

Comment: @Aron "so over time the service will load the entire database into "cache" A web request is not a long timespan. Thus there is no reason IMHO to be afraid of the snapshot cell comparison. If it would be that big perf topic it would be much more known and I never read about it :-)

Comment: @Elisa, ah. Right. That is the correct way, to scope your context to the request. I didn't read the init function, and I thought you meant to have a shared global context. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using transaction scope instead of a dbcontexttransaction:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                                            new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted }))
    {

  // Your code

 scope.Complete();

}
```

Note when you use this across databases it will use MSDTC.

Comment: Because of your "Note". Across database you mean when i would have multiple opened connections AND different connections I guess?

Comment: I did as you said and used the TransactionScope instead of the extra UnitOfWork class. Then I did a positive + negative integration test with the service containing the TransactionScope and it worked fine. I updated my question with the final code!

Answer (score 3):

You don't change your repositories but you definitely lack the **Unit of Work** in your architecture. This is where you share a single context for multiple repositories.

Think of the UoW as the DbContext where repositories are DbSets.

```
UoW uow = new UoW( context );

uow.BeginTransaction();

uow.Repository1.... // query, insert, update, delete
uow.Repository2....

uow.Commit();
```

A typical implementation just exposes multiple repositories:

```
public class UoW {

   public UoW( DbContext ctx ) {

      this._ctx = ctx;

   }

   private Repository1 _repo1;

   public Repository1 Repo1
   {
      get
      {
          if ( _repo1 == null )
              _repo1 = new Repository1( this._ctx );
          return _repo1;
      }

      ...
```

If you need a good and complete tutorial on that, take a look here:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Seems like another nearly unneeded abstraction over my repositories. The only difference to my implementation is that the SaveChanges() of each repository has now moved into the UoW class. Thats typically but not in yours - I guess the 3 dots  mean the same... - What speaks against the solution from user Shiraz ?

Comment: Unneeded? You can be one of those who believe Repositories are not necessary since DbContext is already well-baked. Take a look at my explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19059282/941240. Both approaches are valid - you can go with the DbContext only or you can have repositories/uow over your data access. Point is : having only repositories **without** the uow means you have issues, starting from yours where it is unclear where to put the responsibility of transactions.

Comment: I agree with you, @WiktorZychla, through the design time I realized that repositories should not control when they save things, because different repositories might be interdependent, and we might need a couple of them to commit as a single transaction. But I am not using UoW. I simply call the SaveChanges() outside the repositories in the service consumers (e.g. Controllers). Is there something I gain by implementing a UoW class. I think DbContext is already built to be a UoW class.

Comment: @Ghasan: yes, it is. If you don't plan to ever switch to another data access technology, sticking with db context is a good option.